# HP ProLiant DL380 G6 (need help)

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, boot

I have a Problem with mit DL380 G6.
since few months i started my server for the first time again and the G6 wont boot anymore.
the fans goes louder and louder for a minute and then it shutdown by itself.
then i can hear a tock sound that tocks like a real clock.
changing the RAM, Power supplies and CPU without success.

I postet a video about the problem:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Toaok7UYmX4&feature=youtu.be

Thanks!

Comment: I'd connect to the iLO and look at the Integrated Management Log.

Comment: Also check battery on motherboard with clearing CMOS BIOS data.

Comment: @Mark Wagner - how can i connect the G6 to a iLo? Because the server won't boot up - black screen, no reaction

Comment: @Mikhail Khirgiy - tried it before, no success.

Comment: Time to contact vendor support.

Answer (score 1):

Configure your ILO. If it's not configured and you have no video output, then follow [see here](https://serverfault.com/questions/465883/hp-proliant-dl360-g7-hangs-at-power-and-thermal-calibration-screen) and follow the troubleshooting steps:

[image]

If nothing there works, try to use the steps I posted here:

[ProLiant DL380 G7 won't boot, solid amber power LED](https://serverfault.com/questions/613392/proliant-dl380-g7-wont-boot-solid-amber-power-led/613396#613396)

But here's a (lengthy) troubleshooting procedure to try...

> - Remove the power supply units and swap them.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Locate the *System Maintenance Switch* on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
> - Turn switch #6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Turn DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is system is (rightly or wrongly) thinking it is overheating: continously increasing fan speed could mean it tries to reduce heat.

From the manual:

- At POST and in the OS, iLO 2 performs an orderly shutdown if a
  cautionary temperature level is detected.
- If the server hardware
  detects a critical temperature level before an orderly shutdown
  occurs, the server performs an immediate shutdown.
- When the Thermal
  Shutdown feature is disabled in RBSU, iLO 2 does not perform an
  orderly shutdown when a cautionary temperature level is detected.
- Disabling this feature does not disable the server hardware from
  performing an immediate shutdown when a critical temperature level is
  detected.

Maybe need to change termal sensors or see if there is some source of overheating.
The clicking sound used to be associated with faulty hard drives, also sometime when they were too cold/too hot.

However, in order to understand what is wrong with system, your best bet is to get ILO logs, as suggested in comments.

Check, if you can access ILO despite black screen via its network port. If I remember correctly, ILO should be accessible even if system is powered off (but connected to electricity obviously).

You might have to enable System maintenance switch on motherboard (set S1 to ON), disabling ILO security, to do that.

HP iLO2 guide: http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c00553302.pdf

HP Proliant DL380 G6 guide: http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01705681&lang=en-us&cc=us

Answer (score 0):

This surely is a late answer, but I'll go for it anyway since there is no accepted answer.

This may (as [Gnudiff](https://serverfault.com/users/7747/gnudiff) stated) be a cooling issue. The fans go haywire like that if one or more of the fan-slots are not populated or recognized as populated. This may easily be checked in iLO2 at *System Status* -> *System Information* -> *Fans* (verified path in iLO2 version 2.32).

[Fans-page in iLO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKXu1.png)

If you find that any of the slots are marked as "n/a" then you have either not populated that slot or you have a faulty fan in said slot.