# HP ProLiant ML370 G6 shows no sign of life after RAM upgrade

Tags: electrical-power

I have power issues with my HP ProLiant ML370 G6 server after Ram upgrade. This server has been running without interruption for a very long time and when we decided to power it off to upgrade RAM we couldn't power  it on again. It looks like th MB recives no power. In the trobleshooting process we replaced one of our redundant power supplies with a new one. Nothing changed. All leds on the MB are off. Power supply leds are off. Though power supply fans are spinning. I've already tried basic trobleshooting operations for this kind of problems (change power outlet and cable, disconnect any internal component like ram or hard drives). In the end we stopped even tring to power it on and we abbandoned the server with all its components diconnected in a storage room for 3 months. 
Now we decided to give it another chance and when we plugged it on again, mb leds and power button led were on and i could even power it on. Ofcourse we got boot errors for the components missing so I tried to power it back off by pressing for a few seconds the power button but it didn't work and i had to directly unplug it. Now we are back at the beginning because the server is dead again. 
Considering this do you think that the power backplane is the problem? maybe it's capacitors  decharged during this last 3 months and that's the reason why I could power it on for a few minutes?
I also have to tell you that the power button seems damaged. It looks like its always pressed in. Do you think that a damaged power button could cause the total interruption of power to the MB? I thought that when the power button is damaged maybe you cannot turn the server on but you can atleast see some leds on the MB on.
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: What did HP support say?

Comment: Probably nothing, these have been end-of-support for a long time already.

Comment: This falls into the _"why are you asking the internet?"_ category.

Comment: Just wanted to narrow down which component failed. Changing the power backplane board it's not like changing the entire mainboard. Considering how old this server is i defenetly won't change the MB, but if the backplane board is damaged i would consider repairing it.

Answer (score 1):

Call HP please, for support or to buy a part.

For the symptom you have I would suspect a problem with the mainboard.

A bestpractice is to always restart a system before an maintenance, to know the state of the system. As usually if the uptime is more than a year you could have bad condensator on the mainboard, but having the server at off, and restarted reset those components, that allow you to know if your server is still functional before an intervention inside it.

I do a lot of upgrade for customer and I usually told them to restart the day before I come to make sure I dont fall on a bad surprise after the maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

This is becoming an old server. G6 dates back to 2009.

You clearly don't have support, but you can try a few troubleshooting techniques.

See: [ProLiant DL380 G7 won't boot, solid amber power LED](https://serverfault.com/questions/613392/proliant-dl380-g7-wont-boot-solid-amber-power-led/613396#613396)

and look at: [HP DL380 G7 Will Not Power On](https://serverfault.com/questions/825594/hp-dl380-g7-will-not-power-on/825614#825614)

But here's a (lengthy) troubleshooting procedure to try first if you have access to the machine.

> - Remove the power supply units and swap them.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Locate the *System Maintenance Switch* on the motherboard - It's a set of 10 DIP switches.
> - Turn switch #6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switch #6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...
>
> If that doesn't work:
>
> - Remove all power supplies from the chassis
> - Turn DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 switch on.
> - Insert all power supply units.
> - Power on the server and allow it to idle for 3 minutes.
> - Power the server off.
> - Remove all power supplies.
> - Return DIP switches #1, 5 and 6 to off (original) position.
> - Reinsert the power supplies.
> - Power the server on.
>
> Test to see if the system will boot...

Comment: This troubleshooting procedure didn't work as no power reaches the NVRAM. This is not a boot problem. HP provides no support. 3 months ago a colleague tried to fix it  while reciving indications from  HP by phone, they told him to disconnect RAM and fan chage and after that they suggested to replace the MB.

Comment: Ok. Get someone to come evaluate the hardware or replace it. The systems are modular, so you can also replace the power switch. Also see: https://serverfault.com/a/825614/13325